# How do I subscribe to multiple Facebook page messenger webhooks

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to create a single bot which subscribes to multiple facebook page message inboxes. In essence, I'm providing a platform on which I'd like other pages to be able to share my bot logic.

Right now, the only way I've found to subscribe to a Facebook Page's messenger flow is in the developer console of a Facebook App.

[image: Facebook developer console screenshot]

While this is great for testing, eventually I want to subscribe to page events programatically. How do I do that?

Comment: Did you find a solution to it. If yes please help me out

Answer (score 0):

It's not very well documented in the messenger api, but basically each of those entries are subscriptions created in the webhooks part of the graph api.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/

And more specifically:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page/#messages

Essentially, a page has to "install" an app, using the app subscriptions api endpoint. Once it's installed, then an app can request a subscription which includes the callback url of the webhook.